# how to connect to an ftp server?

Tags: cmd, ftp

How do I connect to an FTP server using a command prompt?

The ftp site I am trying to connect to is

ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/

I used to be able to type in ftp ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/ in the command prompt and it would challange me for a username and password

but now it says unknown host.

I can still get to it from a browser

ftp://ftp.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/

Is there something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify the path in the command. You should use `ftp ftp.bom.gov.au` and then `cd /anon/gen/` to change the path.

Comment: thanks heaps.. much appreciated